# Error in generating signed apk

Tags: ionic2, apk, android-studio-2.3

I am getting an error while trying to generate a signed apk for my ionic application. I followed the steps from https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html.

Below is the error image:

[image]

Can someone tell the root cause behind this error.

Comment: can you try with this guide http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html ?

Comment: See this guide for ionic 2+ https://github.com/rotati/wiki/wiki/Deploy-an-Ionic-Android-app-to-Google-Play-Store

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue literally yesterday. I believe there has been an update to Google Messaging Service (GMS). Are you using the plugin Background Geolocation cordova-background-geolocation OR PushWoosh plugin (pushwoosh-cordova-plugin)?

I have not received a permanent fix (I believe the guys in charge need to update their plugin), but a temporary fix is to navigate to `{projectname}-build.gradle`.

You should see a line along the following lines:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
  compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
  compile(name:'tslocationmanager', ext:'aar')
  // logback-android
  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
  compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
  compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
  }
}
```

Change the top line so instead of `11+`, it becomes `11.2.0`.

If not, comment which plugins you are using please.

**Alternatively**

I found a new plugin today which can be used precisely for this, cordova-google-api-version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-google-api-version.

You can install it by running the following:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-google-api-version@latest --save
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me where to find `{projectname}-build.gradle`?

Comment: Hi @aakash-thakur, which plugins do you use? I think that's one specific to Background Geolocation.

Comment: Also, check my edit - there's a plugin which will circumvent this for you which is probably easier.

Comment: I am not using any plugin as mentioned by you. Do i need to reinstall android studio?